# Prove the equivalence between some set $C$ be closed under some operation and de restriction of this operation be a operation in $C$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The question is stated as:

Consider a binary operation on a set $A$
$$F:A \times A \rightarrow A$$
Assume $C \subseteq A$. By the restriction of the operaction $F$ to $C$, we mean the function $G$ such that $Dom(G)=C \times C$ and $G(x,y) = F(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $C$.

a. Prove that the restriction of $G$ of $F$ to $C$ is an operation on $C$ if and only if $C$ is closed under $F$.

Here is my atempt:

- First assume $C$ is closed under $F$, thus we have $(\forall x)(\forall y)([x \in C \land y \in C] \Rightarrow F(x,y) \in C)$

As $F(x,y) = G(x,y)$ for any $x$ and $y$ and $Dom(G) = C \times C \subseteq Dom(F)$, we have that $(\forall x)(\forall y)([x \in C \land y \in C] \Rightarrow G(x,y) \in C)$, and therefore we have $G:C \times C \rightarrow C$, then $G$ is a binary operation on $C$.

- On other hand assume that the restriction $G$ is a binary opeation on $C$, thus we have $G:C \times C \rightarrow C$

We have $C \subseteq A$ and $F(x,y) = G(x,y)$ for any $x$ and $y$, thus $(\forall x)(\forall y)([x \in C] \land y \in C] \Rightarrow G(x,y)=F(x,y) \in C)$, then $C$ is closed under $F$.

As both sides implies in eachother I conclude that he restriction of $G$ of $F$ to $C$ is an operation on $C$ if and only if $C$ is closed under $C$.

This atempt is correct? If not, how it should be proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the argument more clear I will use the notation $F_{|C}$ to mean the function $F$ restricted to the set $C\times C$. It is easy to verify that the restriction of a function is a function. An operation on a set $A$ is simply a function $A\times A \to A$. Using this definition we  have that $F_{|C}$ is an operation on $C$ if and only if it is a function from $C\times C \to C$. We know that it is a function with domain equal to $C\times C$ so $F_{|C}$ is an operation on $C$ if and only if it has range that is a subset of $C$. Finally we have that $C$ is closed under $F$ if and only if $F(C\times C)\subseteq C$ which is the same as $range(F_{|C})=C$ which is the required property for $F_{|C}$ to be an operation on $C$

Comment: $F(C \times C)$ means the application of F over all elements of $C \times C$ like $F(C \times C) = \{z : (\exists x)(\exists y)(x \in C \land y \in C \land z = F(x,y))\}$ ? I liked the notation you used, I just used $G$ because the book did this way.

Comment: yes exactly it's the image of the set CxC. To say that the image of CxC is a subset of C we are saying that for all a,b in C F(a,b) is also in C which is what we mean operation closure. This is the reason why the closure axiom is sometimes omitted when defining the properties of an operation since it is already implied by it's definition as a function

Comment: Thank you for the help.